# fsck and Disk Utility won't repair Volume: invalid b-tree node size

Tags: hard-drive, filesystem, data-recovery, hfs+

I accidentally wrote some `.iso` data to a disk through `dd` by mistake. I cancelled the command after just 2 seconds but that was enough to wipe the first EFI partition (200MB) and a bit of the second partition where OS X and some files I do really like are stored.

The ISO image I accidentally wrote with `dd` was 600mb in size so the total damage would be a maximum of 400 MB since I `dd` from sector 0 until I hit <kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd> and EFI partition was gone.

I tried running `fsck -fy` on that partition but it's a no-go.

```
sudo fsck_hfs -fy /dev/disk2s2
** /dev/rdisk2s2
Using cacheBlockSize=32K cacheTotalBlock=32768 cacheSize=1048576K.
Executing fsck_hfs (version diskdev_cmds-557~393).
** Checking Journaled HFS Plus volume.
Invalid B-tree node size
```

I don't know much about HFS+ but on any EXT Linux partition I could pretty much recover everything that wasn't wiped by `dd`, even if overwritten. Here however I don't know where to start. There are some fancy GUI tools but they probably won't do anything else then `fsck` does.

It can't be that the whole partition is gone because 400 MB (if the whole ISO would be written - but that wasn't the case) out of 400 GB was overwritten with data by accident. Partition table seems to be alright - `gdisk` on Linux says it's OK and Disk Utility on Mac as well.

Volume was journaled (seems to be a problem for HFS+ utilities on Linux)

Any tips how to rescue my files?

Comment: All about fsck -- https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/fsck_hfs.8.html

Comment: Read this http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/56461/repair-disk-from-single-user-mode-fsck-fails

Answer (score 2):

Download [Testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Download). You would have to run it from an external disk. It’s a command line tool. It will diagnose problems with your partition table or filesystem and repair them. It’s very verbose so you won’t need any readmes. First recover your OS X partition and then your EFI partition. Comment back if you need any help using Testdisk.

Comment: Hi Guys. Thanks for the answer. TestDisk does not goes well with journaled volumes == everything past 10.4 is journaled by default as far as I can say.

Comment: Um, no. Testdisk was developed after Apple introduced jorunaled HFS+. It works very well with all types of filesystems.

Answer (score 1):

You should to try to rebuild the catalog file on the specified file system by specifying `-r` option, for example:

```
$ fsck.hfsplus -fryd /dev/sdd2
```

See also: [How to fix invalid map node linkage?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/160068/how-to-fix-invalid-map-node-linkage)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get data back using Photorec but was unable to get original filenames or directory structures.

I did find R-Studio https://r-studio.com which recovered the entire file and folder structure. It's a paid product but worked out well.

Still can't fix the Invalid B-tree node size issue. It almost seems like a partition issue.

Answer (score -3):

Use [DiskWarrior](http://www.alsoft.com/DiskWarrior/).  Has saved many of my client's disks!