# fsck not working to fix corrupted external drive

Tags: macos, external-disk, filesystem, fsck

I am using an early 2011 MacBook Pro with the Mavericks OS. I've researched a similar issue on an [internal drive](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/56461/repair-disk-from-single-user-mode-fsck-fails) but As far as I know, being in Single User mode won't help my situation.

One of my external drives with all my photos stopped working - it does not mount, even though I see it in Disk Utility.
Using DU I tried to verify and repair the disk and got this message:

'Invalid B-tree node size'

Following the advice in this [link](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/130304/how-can-i-repair-a-disk-that-disk-utility-says-it-cant-repair-this-disk):

I tried to list my drives with the Terminal command

`df -hl`

The specificied disk was not in the list
When I tried the suggested `tail` command

`tail -f /var/log/fsck_hfs.log`

I saw the name of the disk as

```
/dev/rdisk3s2: ** The volume   could not be verified completely.
```

Following that, I used this command (also suggested in the above link)

`sudo fsck_hfs -r -d /dev/disk3s2`

Instead of the expected proper outcome, what I received was an error message in Terminal as below:

```
inancs-MacBook-Pro:~ INCA$ sudo fsck_hfs -r -d /dev/disk3s2
Password:
journal_replay(/dev/disk3s2) returned 0
** /dev/rdisk3s2
    Using cacheBlockSize=32K cacheTotalBlock=65536 cacheSize=2097152K.
   Executing fsck_hfs (version hfs-226.1.1).
** Checking Journaled HFS Plus volume.
   Invalid B-tree node size
(3, 0)
** The volume   could not be verified completely.
    volume check failed with error 7 
    volume type is pure HFS+ 
    primary MDB is at block 0 0x00 
    alternate MDB is at block 0 0x00 
    primary VHB is at block 2 0x02 
    alternate VHB is at block 1464477326 0x574a268e 
    sector size = 512 0x200 
    VolumeObject flags = 0x07 
    total sectors for volume = 1464477328 0x574a2690 
    total sectors for embedded volume = 0 0x00 
    CheckHFS returned -1317, fsmodified = 0
```

What are my options?
I have Data Rescue but not Disk Warrior (low on budget these days).
Is there a possibility to fix the drive?

If not, and if I can rescue my data and put it on a different disk, is it safe to format the current drive and re-add my photos or should i stay away from this disk?